# SELECT INTO from Table to Table with GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data from one temporary table into another using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but I'm getting the following error:

`Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.`

Here's the relevant line of code:

```
SELECT '1200.005.032' AS GlCode, upd.Job AS Reference, Sum(upd.DiffValue) AS [Value], 
    'New Overhead Rate Change by $' + upd.RateDifference + ' Job: ' + upd.Job AS Comment, upd.PostYear, upd.PostMonth, 'POSITIVE' as TranType
INTO #LabGenJournal
FROM #UpdLaborDetails upd
GROUP BY '1200.005.032', upd.Job, 'New Overhead Rate Change by $' + upd.RateDifference + 'Job: ' + upd.Job, upd.PostYear, upd.PostMonth
HAVING (((Sum(upd.DiffValue))<>0));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by a constant value ('1200.005.032', a value that doesn't come from the source tables, so a pure "outer reference"). Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    '1200.005.032' AS GlCode,
    upd.Job AS Reference,
    Sum(upd.DiffValue) AS [Value], 
    'New Overhead Rate Change by $' + upd.RateDifference + ' Job: ' + upd.Job AS Comment,
    upd.PostYear,
    upd.PostMonth,
    'POSITIVE' as TranType
INTO #LabGenJournal
FROM #UpdLaborDetails upd
GROUP BY upd.Job, upd.RateDifference, upd.PostYear, upd.PostMonth
HAVING (Sum(upd.DiffValue)<>0);
```

Answer (score 2):

One easy and readable way would be using a [sub-select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/subselects-in-queries?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT t.GlCode, t.Reference, t.Comment, t.PostYear, t.PostMonth, SUM(t.[Value]) DiffValue
INTO #LabGenJournal
FROM 
    (
        SELECT '1200.005.032' AS GlCode, upd.Job AS Reference, upd.DiffValue AS [Value], 'New Overhead Rate Change by $' + upd.RateDifference + ' Job: ' + upd.Job AS Comment, upd.PostYear, upd.PostMonth, 'POSITIVE' as TranType
        FROM #UpdLaborDetails upd
    ) t
GROUP BY t.GlCode, t.Reference, t.Comment, t.PostYear, t.PostMonth
HAVING SUM([Value]) <> 0
```

Another one, using a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WITH cte as 
(
    SELECT '1200.005.032' AS GlCode, upd.Job AS Reference, upd.DiffValue AS [Value], 'New Overhead Rate Change by $' + upd.RateDifference + ' Job: ' + upd.Job AS Comment, upd.PostYear, upd.PostMonth, 'POSITIVE' as TranType
    FROM #UpdLaborDetails upd
)
SELECT t.GlCode, t.Reference, t.Comment, t.PostYear, t.PostMonth, SUM(t.[Value]) DiffValue
INTO #LabGenJournal
FROM cte t
GROUP BY t.GlCode, t.Reference, t.Comment, t.PostYear, t.PostMonth
HAVING SUM([Value]) <> 0
```